# In Blazor Framework, Component defined under a sub-folder in shared folder is not working

Tags: blazor

Within the application wants to create some custom components within a shared folder. For better maintenance, added a folder within the shared folder and create components within that folder. But while using those components on the page, the related custom components work working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you faced the same issue, then just edit the Project file using Visual Studio and in that file u can see the below like codes -

```html
 <ItemGroup>
    <remove Include="Shared\BasicComponent.razor" />
    <remove Include="Shared\Folders\Basic1Component.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Shared\BasicComponent.razor" />
    <None Include="Shared\Folders\Basic1Component.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In the above code remove the part related to the remove keyword and if require, you can remove the ItemGroup Node entirely for the remove tag.